# PHP MySQL zip code to lat/lon then sorted by distance query not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following two queries, the first one takes a (posted) zip code from a previous page entered by the user and finds the corresponding lat and lon in the zip code database. The second query should take that data and sort anything within 100 miles by distance.

It isn't working, though the web page loads fine, I am not returning any results, even when I try adding a zip code in the database. Can anybody see what I am doing wrong?

```
$colname_LOCATION = "-1";
if (isset($_POST['ZIPCODE'])) {
$colname_LOCATION = $_POST['ZIPCODE'];  //Zip code taken from customer form on previous    page
}
mysql_select_db($database_XMASTREE, $XMASTREE); // find lat and lon from fields    inZIP_FULL zipcode database
$query_LOCATION = sprintf("SELECT * FROM ZIP_FULL WHERE zip_code = %s",     GetSQLValueString($colname_LOCATION, "int")); 
$LOCATION = mysql_query($query_LOCATION, $XMASTREE) or die(mysql_error());
$row_LOCATION = mysql_fetch_assoc($LOCATION);
$totalRows_LOCATION = mysql_num_rows($LOCATION);

$lat = $row_LOCATION['latitude']; // code said to change $lat with a number so hopefully this will do it 
$lon = $row_LOCATION['longitude']; // code said to change $lon with a number so hopefully this will do it

mysql_select_db($database_XMASTREE, $XMASTREE);
$query_DIST = "SELECT ((ACOS(SIN($lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS($lat   * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS(($lon - lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60  * 1.1515) AS distance 
FROM MEMBERS 
HAVING distance <= 100
ORDER BY distance ASC";
$DIST = mysql_query($query_DIST, $XMASTREE) or die(mysql_error());
$row_DIST = mysql_fetch_assoc($DIST);
$totalRows_DIST = mysql_num_rows($DIST);
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: thamks, I will look a that. I was using Dreamweaver CS6 which put in the mysql_* stuff - still learning, and that was helpful, thank you, will indeed look into the better new ways.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Do you get an sql error? or do you get a page error? Try to `var_dump()`your code to see what's actually going on.

Comment: Can you please post some table data so we can try solving this using a sample of your dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I've modified code that I created just last week and should do what you want.
Your MySQL code looked good at a glance.

```
$colname_LOCATION = "-1";
if (isset($_POST['ZIPCODE'])) {
$colname_LOCATION = $_POST['ZIPCODE'];  //Zip code taken from customer form on previous    page
}

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("$dbInfo[type]:host=$dbInfo[host];dbname=$dbInfo[dbname]", $dbInfo['username'], $dbInfo['password']);
    $query_LOCATION = "SELECT * FROM ZIP_FULL WHERE zip_code = :zip_code";
    $stmt->bindParam(':zip_code', $colname_LOCATION, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row_LOCATION = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $lat = $row_LOCATION['latitude'];
    $lon = $row_LOCATION['longitude'];

    $bounding_distance = 10; //$bounding_distance is an easy way to narrow down the search, without MySQL doing all of the distance calcs  
    $sql = "SELECT *
            ,((ACOS(SIN(:find_lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(`lat` * PI() / 180) + COS(:find_lat * PI() / 180) * COS(`lat` * PI() / 180) * COS((:find_long - `lon`) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.15078) AS `distance` 
            FROM `MEMBERS` 
            WHERE
                `lat` BETWEEN (:find_lat - :bounding_distance) AND (:find_lat + :bounding_distance)
                AND `lon` BETWEEN (:find_long - :bounding_distance) AND (:find_long + :bounding_distance)
                AND `distance` <= 100
            ORDER BY `distance` ASC;"; 
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(':find_lat', $lat);
    $stmt->bindValue(':find_long', $lon);
    $stmt->bindValue(':bounding_distance', $bounding_distance);

    $stmt->execute();
    $row_DIST = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $totalRows_DIST = count($row_DIST);
    $pdo = NULL;
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    pdo_error($e,$sql);
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, it was way over my head though, I have no idea how to implement it :) Going to have to do some tutorials somewhere :)